# How to hide the scrollbar by clicking in a botton using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, scrollbar

How can I create a function in JavaScript to hide and show a scrollbar by clicking in a button?

I've already tried to do it but it didn't work.

Comment: Please, [edit] to create a [mcve]. Take a [tour] (since you have not), and most importantly, read [ask].

Comment: Do you wish to (A) completely disable scrolling, or to (B) allow scrolling but visually-hide the scroll bar? If (A), that is really easy with CSS: `overflow: hidden`. If (B), that is not so simple and there are many approaches. It potentially involve tricks with margins and/or multiple overlapping elements. Whatever you do, you will be wrestling with it forever. In any case, what is the reasoning for this? Do you have a special circumstance that is different than what occurs on millions of websites and apps, where users expect certain universal UI behaviour?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have a created website. So, I have a hamburger button when you access the website from smaller devices. I need to block the scrolling by clicking on this button and unblock the scrolling by clicking it again.